# Formal development of Ito calculus?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus

I've been reading about Ito Calculus, but most of it has been non-formal, applied stuff. They talk a bit about deriving Ito's lemma using Taylor expansion, and about Ito Integration. But they don't actually formally develop the Ito integral from the ground up. [This](http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-Ito.pdf) is the best text I've found, but at the top of page 3, it still just "tells" you (without proof) what the squared variation of the Brownian motion is.

**So my question is: do you have a good, clear text, that formally develops Ito calculus from the ground up, with proofs?**

Answer (score 1):

I very much like Lawrence C. Evans: *An introduction to stochastic differential equations* (AMS, ISBN 978-1-4704-1054-4). I admit, though, that I have mostly been reading the part of the book that comes after the introduction of Brownian motion and the Itô integral.